# how to get magento table name

Tags: php, sql, magento, module, installation

I have this global config:

```
<global>
    <models>
    <subscriber>
        <class>Giftlab_Subscriber_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>subscriber_resource</resourceModel>
    </subscriber>
    <subscriber_resource>
        <class>Giftlab_Subscriber_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <records>
                <table>subscriber_records</table>
            </records>
        </entities>
    </subscriber_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <giftlab_subscriber_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </giftlab_subscriber_write>
        <giftlab_subscriber_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </giftlab_subscriber_read>
        <giftlab_subscriber_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Giftlab_Subscriber</module>
                <class>Giftlab_Subscriber_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </giftlab_subscriber_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

in my mysql4-install-0.1.0.php file, I need to get the table name. How do I do it?
I know it is something like this:

```
$this->getTable('subscriber_resource/records')
```

But that only produces an exception `Can't retrieve entity config: subscriber_resource/records`. What do I need to do to retrieve the table name?

Comment: To be honest I always knew the tablename, the $this->getTable('some/thing') just adds the pre and suffixes. So actually if you ass the name of the table it works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured out the answer myself, although thanks to @Yaroslav for directing my to Alan Storm's tutorial, as that helped.

The answer is, I need this:

```
$this->getTable('subscriber/records');
```

where "subscriber" is the name of the config entry for the model (not the resource), and "records" is the entity. Turns out that when magento parses thinga/thingb, it always assumes that thinga before the slash is the model and dereferences that to get the resource, by looking in the config for `<thinga><resourceModel>{resourcemodel}`, and then looking again for `<{resourcemodel}><entities><thingb><table>` to get the table name.

So my config was correct, I was just getting confused between the idea of model and resource. Hope this helps someone else getting stuck on the same problem - I couldn't find any clear info on this in the various tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the table name of a resource that does **not** have a resource model (like `catalog/category_product`) and you are **not** in a setup script, you can do it this way:

```
$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category_product');
```

This is helpful for all N:M relations where you usually does not need a model class.

Comment: ↑↑↑ This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

On Magento you work with `Collections`. See a sample:

```
$mysubscriber_recordsCollection = Mage::getModel('records/subscriber_records')->getCollection()
```

Check useful Alan Storm site, specially the [tutorial on Magento models](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm).

**EDIT**

To get table names on the setup install here is a detailed sample. Pay attention to the `$installer->getTable('records/subscriber_records')` here is where table name is loaded.

```
<?php
    echo 'Running This Upgrade: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
        CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('records/subscriber_records')}` (
            `subscriber_records_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARY KEY (`subscriber_records_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    ");
    $installer->endSetup();
```

For the setup resources check this other [Alan Storm's tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources)

Comment: Yes, but that is too high level - here I said I am trying to get the table name in the install sql, this is actually where I will be creating the table, so I can't use getModel yet.

Comment: Ouch! You're right. Edited and added what you are looking for. Keeping the other code just as a bonus ;)